# Adding a yii2 view when sending a html email

Tags: yii2

I have this code in my yii2 application that i am using to send emails with sendgrid. It connects well to sendgrid but does not include images

```
 public function actionApi()
    {
    echo Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp(date('Y-d-m h:i:s'));
    
    //$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('rooms');
    //$collection->insert(['name' => 'John Smith', 'status' => 1]);
    $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
    $message = $mailer->compose()
    ->setTo('rod@yahoo.mx')  
    ->setFrom(['info@google.mx' => 'Mexico City])
    ->setReplyTo('info@google.mx')
    ->setSubject('Your package is here')
    ->setHtmlBody('Your package is here')
    ->setHtmlBody($this->render('app_launch'))
    ->send();

    if ($message === true) {
        echo 'Success!';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($mailer->getRawResponses(), true) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!<br>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($mailer->getErrors(), true) . '</pre>';
    }
    
    }
```

of the template attached. How can i display the images when sending html emails? Is there a way i can reference the view file absolutely here

```
->setHtmlBody($this->render('app_launch'))
```

to be able to send the emails?

Comment: You need to embed images first. Read https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing#embedding-images

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing#embedding-images. End to get html text without view template you can use $this->renderPartial("your_view_file");

And I think you only need one html body.